# Can't locate CGIBook/Error.pm

Tags: macos, perl

I am new to perl. I am running a perl script on macbook and i get following error:

```
Can't locate CGIBook/Error.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-
multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.12 /Network/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-thread-multi-2level
/Network/Library/Perl/5.12 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.12.3 /System/Library/Perl/5.12/darwin-
thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.12 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12/darwin-
thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.12) at HW1_3A.pl line 5.
```

It looks like I don't have CGIBook in my perl directory. Is that correct? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find [CGIBook::Error](https://metacpan.org/search?q=CGIBook%3A%3AError) on CPAN, so it may be a local module or something you got (or should get) from a vendor. Someone may have installed in a different location other than the default module search path.

In this case, it looks like you may be trying to use an example from the ancient book *[CGI Programming with Perl](http://books.google.com/books?isbn=144932679X)*, which created a module with the same name for the examples.

A Google search of the error message quickly led to this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -wT

package CGIBook::Error;

# Export the error subroutine
use Exporter;
@ISA = "Exporter";
@EXPORT = qw( error );

$VERSION = "0.01";

use strict;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw( fatalsToBrowser );

BEGIN {
    sub carp_error {
        my $error_message = shift;
        my $q = new CGI;
        my $discard_this = $q->header( "text/html" );
        error( $q, $error_message );
    }
    CGI::Carp::set_message( \&carp_error );
}

sub error {
    my( $q, $error_message ) = @_;

    print $q->header( "text/html" ),
          $q->start_html( "Error" ),
          $q->h1( "Error" ),
          $q->p( "Sorry, the following error has occurred: " ),
          $q->p( $q->i( $error_message ) ),
          $q->end_html;
    exit;
}

1;
```